# Excel, Using Get Data from Web, one of my URL parameters is being ignored

Tags: excel, excel-formula, export-to-excel

I am using Excel on windows. Attempting to Get Data from Web at the link (1), but when the data loads in Excel, the parameter "&membership=expired" does not apply and the data loads as if the command was not there.

(1) https://usatt.simplycompete.com/userAccount/s2?&membership=expired&pageSize=3

By going the URL (1) in chrome, I can see the url loads the data I expect, 3 entries, with expired memberships. Notice the url in the image.

[image: url 1 image]

**My problem is** the data in excel looks like the url without the &membership=expired" command. Loaded data is only Non-expired memberships. To check this, compare to the image of url (2).

[image: Excel data]

(2) https://usatt.simplycompete.com/userAccount/s2?&pageSize=3

[image: url 2 image]

**Is there a way to get the membership=expired data to load into excel?**

Thank you for your time and any information you can provide,
Cameron

Comment: There shouldn't be a `&` right after the `?`. It's likely technically legal, but maybe throwing something off.

Comment: @GSerg , understood. Unfortunately, removing the & from the url does not fix the issue. The data still loads as if that command was not there (shows only active members).